# Managing a JWT Session with React?

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I have a very general question concerning a JWT Session.

Whenever I fetch something from the database I need to sent the token along to autentificate. In case the token is expired, I need to check if the token is still valid. How do I manage this in a simple fashion? So that the user is directed to a login page whenever the token is invalid?

Do I always have to dispatch my intended action (e. g. a GET req. to fetch news articles) and dispatch a SECOND action everytime which deletes the token from SessionStorage if it is not valid and redirects the user to the login screen? This seems like a bad solutions because it somplicates literally every action?

So my basic question is, how do I manage a JWT session in a good way?

Answer (score -1):

JWT token usually comes with the expiration time, store it in local storage and refresh it when needed.

sample code : https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs/05-token-renewal

Comment: Thanks for that. I've implemented it to the point you described. But now I ask myself how to I handle normal requests with the token i have saved. You see: 1. I need to include the token in every request, which is fine 2. For every request I have to check for the token and sent the user to a login screen if the token is expired (do I do this with a .catch() or with an additional action? this seems a little complicated.

Comment: To check if the user session is expired you just have to check the expirity time. You can use an higher order component in order to automate this check. sample : https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-stack-demo-client/blob/master/src/components/AuthenticatedRoute.js

Comment: Thanks for that! It took some time until I understood what you were proposing. But as far as I understand it, implementing a higher order component is not really a check. It merely asks the application state if some piece of state says that the user is authenticated. To really check if that this is true I would still need to ask the server that supplies the token. So the question remains how this check is performed? Even with your solution I have to append this check to every action seperately.

Comment: Or is it possible to dispatch an action (Redux) within the higher order component?

Comment: The token check is performed server side, by your API

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958952/redirect-using-react-router-in-redux-middleware

Comment: The sample code of the original comment is no more accessible :(